# Program wait till user Input information

Tags: c#

First of all, im sorry if this question was already responded by someone, but im new to Stackoverflow and im trying to make my first program in C# with visual studio.

Im making a bank program with object oriented programmation, i already done a few methods so the user can deposit and withdraw money, but i dont know how to apply this methods to the Console. Here is my code, and what im trying to do is pause the program till the user sets the information needed, the money and the string of the note (like 80$ "dinner with Joe").

```
case "/deposit":
     //Make the deposit
     account.MakeDeposit(Console.Read(), DateTime.Now,Console.ReadLine());
break;
```

The requierements of the method are a decimal for the amount, the date time that is not a problem, and the string.

It only takes the first character of the command line, for example if i want to deposit 8000$ it will only take the 8. Then the option for the string doesnt even pop up. I wanted to make like a console feedback too, so when i run the command /deposit it prints like: "How much money?" and that stuff.

I need help to break down the method in parts so i can inject the decimal ammount and the string.

Any advices, tips and tutorials are welcome.

Ty guys!

Comment: I am sorry but I don't see the question.

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? As is your code waits for 2 user inputs (first a single character, then an entire string)

Comment: It's hard to understand what's going on. What are the parameter types for account.MakeDeposit ? Are you sure you want Console.Read() and not Console.ReadLine() for the first read? Also, it might be easier to catch the values in variables and parse them into typed values (like decimal) before passing them into MakeDeposit

Comment: Yeah, but its doest work properly, it only takes the first character of the command line, for example if i want to deposit 8000$ it will only take the 8. Then the option for the string doesnt even pop up. I wanted to make like a console feedback too, so when i run the command /deposit it prints like: "How much money?" and that stuff

Comment: You can try the following for writing to the console.
Console.WriteLine("Enter deposit amount");
double currency = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Writeline("Ask user something");
var inputvar = Console.Readline();

Console.Writeline("message")  for outputting to the console
and Console.Readline() for reading the input and then you have to parse the input based on your requirements

Comment: If you read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=netframework-4.8) for `Console.Read`, you'll see that it reads the next character in from the input stream. If you replace that with `Console.ReadLine`, it will return the full string entered by the user. You'd still have to convert that do a decimal if that's the required type. As others have said, you should capture (and validate) the input first and then call the method with the captured values.

Comment: Use the `decimal` data type for currency type of values. `double` is not suited at all, unless you like seeing amounts like `1.3999999999997` on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so what i made, as Tarik told me is break down the code, with a method will be better but i created empty variables to store the information code gaved by the user, its a bad way to resolve it but im really new to this so it works for me, here is the code:

```
case "/deposit":

      //Deposit Money

      decimal C;
      string D;
      Console.WriteLine("How much you want to deposit?");
      C = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
      Console.WriteLine("Add a note:");
      D = Console.ReadLine();
      account.MakeDeposit(C, DateTime.Now, D);
      Console.WriteLine($"Maked a deposit of {C.ToString()}$!");

      break;
```

Ty guys for the help!

Any way to improve it will be appreciated guys.

Answer (score 0):

Break down the parts of your application reading input from the console from the parts of the app that process the data. You can then concentrate on one thing at a time. As such, the call to Console.Read does not belong as an argument to account.MakeDeposit. It makes it hard to debug and you will get a mess at the end.

Comment: Thanks Tarik for the answer, thats what i was thinking about it but i dont have the knowledge in this matter to make it, do u have any example or tutorial link of how to break down the method in parts?

Im really sorry but i dont have experience at all about this.

Comment: Create a method that does the reading and store the values in variables. Use Double.Parse to convert from string to double, and store that in separate variables. You are then ready to call your deposit function.

Answer (score 0):

To wait for user input use `string input = Console.ReadLine();`

Then to convert the string into an amount use

```
if( decimal.TryParse(input, out decimal amount)) 
{
    // success! do something with 'amount'
} 
else 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input. Expected decimal value");
}
```